# How to type named, optional parameter that accepts an object with optional fields that have defaults in TypeScript-React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, typing

I want something like the `style` prop in the default HTML components:

```
 <div ref={ref} style={{ overflow: 'visible', height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
```

`style` itself is an optional prop, and the fields inside the object passed to `style` are optional too (and I assume they have defaults). I wish I could just look at the source code to figure out how it's done, but it just looks like complete gibberish to me.

##### Stuff I tried

```
function a({
  param1 = 'default param1',
  options = { option1: 'default option1', option2: 'default option2' },
}: {
  param1?: string;
  options?: { option1?: string; option2?: string };
}) {
  console.log(param1);
  console.log(options);
}

a({});
a({ param1: 'my param1' });
a({ param1: 'my param1', options: { option1: 'my option1' } });
```

```
[LOG]: "default param1" 
[LOG]: {
  "option1": "default option1",
  "option2": "default option2"
} 
[LOG]: "my param1" 
[LOG]: {
  "option1": "default option1",
  "option2": "default option2"
} 
[LOG]: "my param1" 
[LOG]: {
  "option1": "my option1"
}
```

This almost works but the default for `options` is overridden completely when I only pass in `option1`. How do I set defaults for each field in `options` individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines if you only care about individual options:

```
function a({
  param1 = 'default param1',
  options,
}: {
  param1?: string;
  options?: { option1?: string; option2?: string };
}) {
  const {option1 = 'default option1', option2 = 'default option2'} = options ?? {}
  console.log(param1);
  console.log({option1, option2});
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Object.assign` to build your options objects, e.g.

```
const defaultOptions = {
   option1: 'default option1', 
   option2: 'default option2'
}
function a({
  param1 = 'default param1',
  options,
}: {
  param1?: string;
  options?: { option1?: string; option2?: string };
}) {
  const effectiveOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options)
  console.log(param1);
  console.log(effectiveOptions);
}
```